# Conditionally rendering a child component into Header in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my `react-native` 0.62 app, I created an `<AppHeader />` component to render the header so that I don't have to repeat the same code in every screen.

The title and burger menu are standard and always there but in some screens, I want to add one, two or more buttons to the right section -- see below:

[image]

So, it would be nice to receive and render a component on the right. If no component is received, then I wouldn't render anything and the right side would be blank.

I'm using `native-base` so the header understands `<Left>` and `<Right>`.

My question is how would I pass a component to my `<AppHeader />` and what would the conditional part look like?

Here's my `<AppHeader />` component now:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Icon, Title } from 'native-base';

// Stylesheet
import { styles } from './style-app-header';

const AppHeader = ({ navigation, title, rightSection }) => {

   return (
      <Header transparent>
         <Left style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Button transparent onPress={() => navigation.navigation.openDrawer()}>
               <Icon name="ios-menu" style={styles.icon} />
            </Button>
         </Left>
         <Body style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Title style={styles.title}>{title}</Title>
         </Body>
         {
            rightSection === null
            ? <Right />
            : <Right style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                  // How would I render the component here?
              </Right>
         }
      </Header>
   );
}

export default AppHeader;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React components can be used just like any other variable value.

```
const buttons = <button onClick={someAction}>Click me!</button>;
return (
    <AppHeader rightSection={buttons}/>
);
```

```
// ...
<Right style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    {rightSection}
</Right>
// ...
```

Comment: Way easier than I thought! Thank you!